# React test not resolving dynamic require paths

Tags: reactjs, karma-jasmine, commonjs, webpack

To avoid hardcoding relative paths for every module I load in my test, I wanted to set a base url & concatenate the strings for the require statements (see UserStore-test.js below). When the require statements are hardcoded, everything works, but when I concatenate the strings, it gives me an 'Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "."'

```
//UserStore-test.js
var base = '../../../';
var UserConstants = require('../../..constants/user/UserConstants'); // WORKS
//var UserConstants = require(base + '/constants/user/UserConstants'); // DOESN'T WORK

describe('UserStore', function(){
   ...
});
```

My test config files are below:

```
//karma.conf.js
var webpack = require('webpack');
var RewireWebpackPlugin = require("rewire-webpack");

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    files: [
      'tests.webpack.js'
    ],
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    preprocessors: {
      'tests.webpack.js': ['webpack', 'sourcemap'],
    },
    reporters: ['dots'],
    singleRun: true,
    webpack: {
      devtool: 'inline-source-map',
      module: {
        loaders: [
          { test: /\.js?$/, exclude:/node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader' },
        ],
      },
      watch: true,
      plugins: [new RewireWebpackPlugin()]
    },
    webpackServer: {
      noInfo: true,
    },
  });
};
```

and

```
//tests.webpack.js
var context = require.context('./path/to/files', true, /-test\.js$/);
context.keys().forEach(context);
```

I'm thinking there must be a setting I'm missing in one of my config files (maybe a preprocessor?), but I've been googling around for a while and can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use variables inside a call to `require` in either Webpack or Browserify. The reason for this is that both of them first analyses your code to see which modules you're requiring, but it doesn't actually run your `require` statement as you've written it. They look at what you pass to `require`, normalize that path and adds that module to the dependency tree, and replaces the module name passed to `require` with a module id. So there's no way for them to know the contents of a variable in that analyses step.

There are lots of ways to avoid having require calls start with `../../../` and it's mostly about structuring your code and minimizing dependencies between modules that are far away from each other.

But in your case I assume that you have all test files in another folder than your source files, which is why you need to go up and down in the folder structure. A common solution to that is to place your test files right next to your source files. So your file structure would be something like:

```
src/
  todo/
    component.js
    component.test.js
  app.js
  app.test.js
```

Some people really dislike mixing test files with source files like that, and I did as well, but I've grown to really like that approach as it's very obvious which modules are tested.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the info. That's a pain but I'll look into locating my test files adjacent to the file they're testing.